# JQuery select element by id /class and change display to none

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="A" class="B" style="display:block">asd</div>
<select id="Z" value="a">1</select><select value="b">2</select>
```

I would like to .onchange of select value, trigger the change of class into C, and also visibility into none.

AND select to be disabled (disabled="disabled")

Thank you

Comment: @CheongDMunPong What about your programming issue, have you fixed it? I guess pschueller's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you for your concern, the answer works like a charm, and my question delivered as it should be,i try to keep it simple

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly... then something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#z").change(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $("#A").hide();
        $("#A").attr('class', 'C');
    });
});
```

And make sure to fix your select element:

```
<div id="A" class="B" style="display:block">asd</div>
<select id="z">
    <option value="a">1</option>
    <option value="b">2</option>
    <option value="c">3</option>
    <option value="d">4</option>
</select>
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3sYw/

Comment: is it true that id and class are both selectable by js using #?

Comment: thanks, i think i can answer that, it does, thank you very much

Comment: '#example' targets an ID, '.example' targets a class. In this example we only had to target IDs, but you could of course do it differently.